# Lumify installation with error in vagrant as The box 'nrel/CentOS-6.6-x86_64' could not be found

Tags: java, vagrant, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install lumify in my vmware workstation as follows.

```
$ cd lumify
$ git clone https://github.com/lumifyio/lumify.git
$ cd lumify/lumify
$ vagrant up demo
```

**after running last step vagrant up demo I got error**

```
Bringing machine 'dev' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'demo' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
The box 'nrel/CentOS-6.6-x86_64' could not be found.
```

then in the same directory I did

```
vagrant box add CentOS `https://github.com/tommy-muehle/puppet-vagrant-boxes/releases/download/1.0.0/centos-6.6-x86_64.box`
```

then I did `vagrant up demo`. but still it is showing same error

**Note:in lumify folder already vagrantfile is present**

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, the box `nrel/CentOS-6.6-x86_64` is clearly available in atlas (https://atlas.hashicorp.com/nrel/boxes/CentOS-6.6-x86_64)

which version of vagrant are you running ? you need at least vagrant 1.5 which is able to download boxes from atlas.

you can also install the box manually but respect the name:

```
vagrant box add nrel/CentOS-6.6-x86_64 https://atlas.hashicorp.com/nrel/boxes/CentOS-6.6-x86_64/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```